# InstallationDirectoryChooser / Installation size calculator

Tags: java, install4j

I am trying to show 5 GB in my InstallationDirectoryChooser component and I can not fine the exactly number in bytes I have to use.

For example 4766254545L give me show 5,318 MB and I need to show exactly 5GB

Answer (score 0):

It is not practical to use this script for this purpose, because the size of a bundled JRE will be added to to the returned value.

I would suggest deselecting the "Show required disk space" property of the "Installation directory chooser" form component and add your own "Label" form component whose text is set to

```
${installer:myLabelText}
```

The installer variable `myLabelText` can be updated programmatically in the "Validation script" property of the "Installation directory chooser" form component by calling

```
context.setVariable("myLabelText", newText);
```

This requires install4j 8.0+.